# how to index the elements of a tuple just by receiving the tuple and the starting position

Tags: haskell

I will receive a tuple containing pairs of elements and also an integer with a value of 1 that represents the first position of my tuple, and I want to return a new tuple, where each pair of elements also has its index within the tuple, the function typing looks like this :
function :: [([Char], Int)] -> Int -> [([Char], Int, Int)]

I don't know how to create a new tuple by merging the pairs of the original tuple and their respective indexes, could you help me?

Comment: Could you add an example to your question illustrating possible input and output values? This might help clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If `a :: ([Char], Int)` and `b :: Int`, then:

```
let (c, d) = a in (c, d, b) :: ([Char], Int, Int)
```

In many cases, for example if you don't use `a` in any other way, you can move the pattern match from this `let` up into the location where you bound `a` in the first place to reduce clutter.